# Windows 11 Installer not showing my USB

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, ssd, installer

Currently, I am attempting to run Windows 11 Home/Pro from a USB, on an intel based MacBook Air 2017.

I booted the installation media, and I can bypass all the windows 11 TPM, SecureBoot and RAM requirements by editing the registry, but when It prompts me to choose which volume to install windows on, my 128 GB VITAL USB-3.0 flash drive that I chose to use, doesn't show up. Only my internal SSD, and the volume from which the installer was running from (EFI) shows.

I tried numerous times to format the 128GB USB as NTFS, FAT, and both GUID and MBR. I know my USB ports are working, because I plugged in my 1TB hard drive (which had a copy of macOS Monterey on it), and my 1TB volume showed up.
I don't want to format my internal SSD, or format my 1TB hard drive.

Is there any way to get my USB's to show?
I already tried with other numerous 32GB USB's and they don't show up either. Plus i didn't use the installation media as the target drive.

Comment: Windows does not support installations on USB flash drives.

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft states "You can use installation media (a USB flash drive or DVD) to install a new copy of Windows, perform a clean installation, or reinstall Windows."

Comment: Use **installation media** to install/repair, NOT as the target drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did not use the installation media as the target drive.

Comment: In addition, what's the point of trying to force Windows 11 on an unsuitable computer?

Comment: @harrymc There is technically no force, and second, it's an *experiment*.

Comment: It shouldn't be so hard to understand that because you can and should use USB flash for the installation media - modern OSes shouldn't really be installed from optical media for obvious reasons - it doesn't follow you can install the OS in flash media because, with Windows, you can't and it has nothing to do with it being the same drive - that would be impossible anyway -, it's just because it isn't allowed by the installer, end of story. With most Linux distros you can, with Windows you can't. There's really nothing else to say here other than what was clearly stated in the first comment.

Comment: Please don't act like we're all idiots because the person here showing a serious problem of understanding basic stuff it's you and only you.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's funny then, how I managed to install Windows 11 Pro on a microSD card with 128 GB using the same method, and run it on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @ChanganAuto And like I said, when I plugged in my **USB** 1TB drive, it showed up just fine.

Comment: Wall of text, very unpleasant to read.

Comment: "It prompts me to choose which volume to install Windows on". That is the "target" drive others have mentioned multiple times. As they also noted, the Windows installer will not show removable media in this list.

Answer (score 2):

Windows cannot officially be installed on any portable drives (neither flash drives nor portable hard drives.) This is the reason why it doesn't show up in the Windows installation wizard, and there is no way to make it show up there.

(Microsoft used to support a special ***Windows To Go*** setup, but not anymore, and even back then it was only for enterprises and only on very specific hardware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview).

There are 3rd party tools that can try to install Windows for you from an ISO onto the flash drive (as an installed Windows, and not as a bootable Windows Installer.) **Rufus** has such an option when selecting a Windows ISO, see this [How to install Windows 11 & Windows 10 on a USB drive (Windows To Go)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/install-windows-to-go/)
 guide for step-by-step instructions:
[image]

Comment: I apologize for being a bit annoying, but using Rufus, what would happen after trying to boot up Windows on the MacBook? Would it bring me to the installation OS as always, but allow it to install on itself? Or will it just try to go the windows 11 setup?

Comment: It should boot into an installed Windows (OOBE)

Comment: Okay, and do you suppose I will be able to edit the registry from there? Or will it prevent me from booting it up before I can enter the registry?

Comment: The registry thing is for the installation to go through, this will already have bypassed the official install altogether, so there is no need. (But in general when creating even a bootable installation USB with Rufus it gives you an easy option - and it's enabled by default - to bypass the Windows 11 compatibility.)

Comment: Okay, and I suppose after booting into the setup I can edit the registry anyway to keep it from not booting after a restart, correct? If all this complies, then you have the answer.

Comment: Read again what I wrote... You wouldn't need to edit any registry, not before and not after booting. The whole registry edit is ONLY required for the Windows Installer (which in this case we do not use at all) to allow you to install. Once installed the registry can be changed back and it doesn't matter

Comment: @OyoSoft - **Windows 11 (x64) the only versions that Rufus downloads CANNOT be installed on a non-Inte MacBook.**   Windows 11 on ARM can be installed on MacBook with Apple silicon, but Rufus cannot download the ISO from it's interface. Windows to Go is unsupported by Microsoft and I guaranteed is NOT support on MacBook regardless of if you are talking about x64 or ARM.

Comment: @Ramhound he says he has an "intel based MacBook"

Comment: @YisroelTech - I missed that. However, Windows to Go, likely will not work on Apple hardware.  Windows running barebones on Apple hardware has always, even on Intel processors, while supported has been interesting. By supported, it's more like, it will work without issues if you can figure it out on your own.

Comment: But it should be the same working as running it off a harddrive barebones on Apple hardware (which can 'work') the USB part should make that more complicated (it's not Apples restriction not to install/run Windows on a USB, it's Microsoft's, so the fact that it's a Mac shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Using bootcamp windows support driver and Rufus, the process should be easy.

Comment: @YisroelTech I now use Windows 11 on my MacBook way more than I ever use macOS. Gaming and work is great.

Comment: Great! If my answer answered the question consider accepting it as the answer by ticking the ✔️ on the left of the answer