# Why doesn’t my USB show up in windows setup

Tags: window, setup

I'm trying to set up Windows, and on the Windows setup my USB flash drive doesn't show up.

Please help.

[image: Windows setup]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://superuser.com/questions/1790396/windows-11-installer-not-showing-my-usb/1790405#1790405?